# Correlation significant in each group but non-significant over all?

Tags: correlation

Suppose we test the Pearson correlation between variable $x$ and $y$ in groups $A$ and $B$. Is it possible for the $(x,y)$ correlation to be significant in each of $A$ and $B$, but non-significant when data from both groups are combined? In this case, could you please provide an explanation for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and it could happen all sorts of ways.  One obvious example is when membership of A and B is chosen in some way that reflects the values of x and y.  Other examples are possible, eg @Macro's comment suggests an alternative possibility.

Consider the example below, written in R.  x and y are iid standard normal variables, but if I allocate them to groups based on the relative values of x and y I get the situation you name.  Within group A and group B there is strong statistically significant correlation between x and y, but if you ignore the grouping structure there is no correlation.

[image]

```r
> library(ggplot2)
> x <- rnorm(1000)
> y <- rnorm(1000)
> Group <- ifelse(x>y, "A", "B")
> cor.test(x,y)

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x and y 
t = -0.9832, df = 998, p-value = 0.3257
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.09292  0.03094 
sample estimates:
     cor 
-0.03111 

> cor.test(x[Group=="A"], y[Group=="A"])

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x[Group == "A"] and y[Group == "A"] 
t = 11.93, df = 487, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4040 0.5414 
sample estimates:
   cor 
0.4756 

> cor.test(x[Group=="B"], y[Group=="B"])

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x[Group == "B"] and y[Group == "B"] 
t = 9.974, df = 509, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3292 0.4744 
sample estimates:
   cor 
0.4043 
> qplot(x,y, color=Group)
```

Comment: +1. This is a very clever example that hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 14):

One possibility is that **the effects may be going in different directions in each group and are cancelled out when you aggregate them**. This is also related to how, when you leave out an important interaction term in a regression model, the main effects can be misleading.

For example, suppose in group $\rm A$, the true relationship between the response $y_i$ and the predictor $x_i$ is:

$$ E(y_i|x_i, {\rm Group \ A}) = 1 + x_i $$

and in group $\rm B$,

$$ E(y_i|x_i, {\rm Group \ B}) = 1 - x_i  $$

Suppose group membership is distributed so that $$P({\rm Group \ A}) = 1-P( {\rm Group \ B}) = p$$ Then, if you marginalize over the group membership and calculate $E(y_i|x_i)$ by [Law of Total Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)  you get

\begin{align*} 
E(y_i | x_i) = E( E(y_i|x_i,{\rm Group}) ) &= p(1+ x_i) + (1-p)(1-x_i) \\
&= p + px_i + 1  - x_i  - p + px_i \\
&= 1 - x_i(2p-1)
\end{align*}

Therefore, if $p = 1/2$, $E(y_i | x_i) = 1$ and does not depend on $x_i$ at all. So, there is a relationship within both groups but, when you aggregate them, there is no relationship. In other words, for a randomly selected individual in the population, whose group membership we don't know, there will, on average, be no relationship between $x_i$ and $y_i$. But, within each group there is.

Any example where the value of $p$ perfectly balances the effect sizes within each group would also lead to this result - this was just this toy example to make the calculations easy :)

**Note:** With normal errors, significance of a linear regression coefficient is equivalent to significance of the Pearson's correlation, so this example highlights one explanation for what you're seeing.